# How to Run confirm() and submit() within a single onclick

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I am using a combination of jQuery and PHP and I have an issue with the jQuery side of things.

I have a select with diffrent options, all of these options have a different confirm() and a different form to submit.

I have put in the onclick:

```
<option value="CANCEL" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to cancel the claim?');  $('#CANCEL').submit();">Cancel Claim</option>
```

However I just get the confirm message and if I click yes it doesn't submit the form.

I assume I would need to do something a bit more advance to tie the confirm() and submit() together. Any ideas?

Below is a snippet

```
<select name="CLAIM_ACTION" style="text-align:center; float:right; margin: 0px 10px 0px 0px;">
    <option value="">Select an Action</option>
    <option value="CANCEL" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to cancel the claim?');  $('#CANCEL').submit();">Cancel Claim</option>
    <option value="CLOSE" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to close the claim?');" >Close Claim</option>
    <option value="WOFF" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to write off the claim?');">Write Off</option>
    <option value="REOPEN" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to re-open the claim?');">Re-open Claim</option>
</select>
<form name="CANCEL" action="claims.php?claimID=<?php echo $claim; ?>&claimTab=Info" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="CANCELVALUE" value="CANCEL" hidden />
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with -

```
<option value="CANCEL" onclick="check_confirmed()">Cancel Claim</option>
```

And

```
function check_confirmed()
{
    if(confirm('Are you sure you want to cancel the claim?')) {
        $('#CANCEL').submit();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems logical however I cannot get anything to execute after the confirm. even the following does not alert: `if(confirm('Are you sure you want to cancel the claim?')) {
             alert("TEST");
            }`

Comment: Hi @Sougata yeah turns out my code wasn't refreshing and when it did I actually needed to use id="CANCEL" not name="CANCEL" and it worked perfectly. Thanks again.